# Query calculating AVG per minute GROUP BY timestamp

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query the average for each minute, so I can generate graph per 5, 15, 30 minutes.

Here is my table, date stored in MySQL DateTime data type field.

```
timestamp            vif_2_rx    
-------------------  ------------
2015-04-16 10:10:00  3.250400    
2015-04-16 10:14:40  593.508800  
2015-04-16 10:14:40  593.508800  
2015-04-16 10:24:40  153.693100   
2015-04-16 10:24:40  153.693100  
2015-04-16 10:29:55  54.976200   
2015-04-16 10:34:40  124.285100  
2015-04-16 10:34:40  124.285100  
2015-04-16 10:34:40  124.285100  
2015-04-16 10:39:55  49.292200   
2015-04-16 10:44:45  56.090700   
2015-04-16 10:44:45  56.090700   
2015-04-16 10:44:45  56.090700   
2015-04-16 10:49:55  20.641100   
2015-04-16 10:54:45  21.694600   
2015-04-16 10:54:45  21.694600
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP, vif_2_rx FROM md_metrics_status WHERE vm_name = 'r-23-VM' 
AND TIMESTAMP > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE 
GROUP BY MINUTE(TIMESTAMP);
```

Results:

```
TIMESTAMP            vif_2_rx    
-------------------  ------------
2015-04-16 10:04:40  94.752800   
2015-04-16 10:10:00  3.250400    
2015-04-16 10:14:40  593.508800  
2015-04-16 11:20:00  14.756200   
2015-04-16 10:24:40  153.693100  
2015-04-16 10:29:55  54.976200   
2015-04-16 13:30:00  76.920200   
2015-04-16 10:34:40  124.285100  
2015-04-16 10:39:55  49.292200   
2015-04-16 10:44:45  56.090700   
2015-04-16 10:49:55  20.641100   
2015-04-16 09:54:45  43.382700   
2015-04-16 11:59:55  78.070000
```

I'm guessing this would only pick a value from that minute without calculating the average of it, how can I go about calculating the average of each minute.

Any ideas on how I can go about doing that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use `AVG` function if you need to get the average
2. Using `MINUTE` function will return the minute part from the date. i.e. 10:05:03 and 11:05:33 will give the same result. (It is fine if the interval is less than 60 minutes, however, it is safer to use the following query:)

`SELECT left(timestamp, 16) as mtimestamp, avg(vif_2_rx) 
FROM md_metrics_status 
WHERE vm_name = 'r-23-VM' AND TIMESTAMP > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE 
GROUP BY mtimestamp`